# Resizing a UIImageView from its Centre Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, scaling

I'm trying to use a slider to grow and image:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChangedSizeOfTarget:(UISlider *)slider {
    [puckImagePrev setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(slider.value, slider.value)];
}
```

However when it does this it doesn't grow from its centre point. Despeite the fact i have got the image set as centred in the properties window.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem caused by AutoLayout. Try disabling it and see what happens then.